# Python issue with fitting a custom function containing double integrals

Tags: python, numpy, integral, custom-function

I want to fit some data using a custom function which contains a double integral. a,b, and c are pre-defined parameters, and alpha and beta are two angles on which the function must be integrated.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import integrate

x=np.linspace(0,100,100)
a=100
b=5
c=1

def custom_function(x,a,b,c):

f = lambda alpha,beta: (np.pi/2)*(np.sin(x*a*np.sin(alpha)*np.cos(beta))/x*a*np.sin(alpha)*np.cos(beta))*(np.sin(x*b*np.sin(alpha)*np.sin(beta))/x*b*np.sin(alpha)*np.sin(beta))*(np.sin(x*c*np.cos(alpha))/x*c*np.cos(alpha))*np.sin(alpha)
return integrate.dblquad(f, 0, np.pi/2, 0, np.pi/2)
```

when running the code, I get the following error:

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'float'>

I've tried simplyfing the function but I still get the same issue, anyone could help me locate the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are not trying to multiply sinc functions, `sin(x*u)/(x*u)`? Currently you are multiplying terms like `u * sin(x*u) / x` because there are not parenthesis in the denominator.

You should be able to fit your function for small `a`,`b`,`c`. But having `a = 100`, you should have a much higher resolution, I would say steps.

I am asuming you are trying to fit using some local minimization method.
If you have a function with more than many maxima and minima while you are trying to fit you are likely to get stuck. You could try some of [non-convex optimization methods available](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#global-optimization)
as well

Comment: Thank you for your input, I've put the denominator parts between brackets but unfortunately I still get the same error. I tried also simplyfing the function to only the first term  ``` (np.pi/2)*(np.sin(x*a*np.sin(alpha)*np.cos(beta))/(x*a*np.sin(alpha))  ``` but I still get the same error. I have a feeling it has to do with the way I defined the integral.

Comment: You are probably having a zero division error, as zero is included in your `x`. To avoid zero division you could write in terms of [numpy.sinc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sinc.html)